# How to get the current Vi mode in IPython

Tags: ipython, powerline

I'm writing a Powerline theme for IPython and I'd like to show the Vi mode in the prompt. That will be useful but is it possible? Does IPython provide a method? I couldn't find it.

This is what I want (now the `INSERT` segment is hard coded):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since IPython has switched to [`prompt_toolkit`](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit) it does not, indeed, respect `.inputrc`, there are plane to do so but `prompt_toolkit` (PTK) author need to find time (or funds to work on it...).

PTK have a vi input mode which is not perfect (Bug reports and PR welcome), and can be enable in IPython. Better than just give you the answer, here is how to find it yourself. run `ipython` with `--help-all` option, grep for `vi`, and keep a couple of lines after (-A2) and after before (-B2):

```
$ ipython --help-all | grep vi -B2 -A2
...snip...
--TerminalInteractiveShell.editing_mode=<Unicode>
    Default: 'emacs'
    Shortcut style to use at the prompt. 'vi' or 'emacs'.
...snip...
```

So there you go, you can start IPython with `--TerminalInteractiveShell.editing_mode='vi'`, or set the configuration option in the IPython configuration file `c.TerminalInteractiveShell.editing_mode='vi'`.

You can also find all configuration options in the [online IPython documentation](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html).